# How do I find text features and print them?

Tags: python, nltk

I have just started using Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) as a part of my Engineering college project. Can anybody please tell me how do I **read an input paragraph text** and

1) break it down into textual components i.e into **number of sentences, number of words, number of characters and number of polysyllabic or complex words** in the given paragraph

and

2) Also **print** the above determined values

Answer (score 0):

Where's the input paragraph coming from? File? Console? That's more of a python issue than NLTK.

For the rest, look at the nltk.tokenize module & nltk.probability.FreqDist.

Comment: The input paragraph comes from both the console and a file. I need to use the number of sentences, words, characters and complex words to find the readability score of the input text.

Comment: Once you have the text, nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize will give you the number of sentences, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize the number of words, and of course len(text) the number of characters. But I don't know of a way to determine if a word is complex or not - maybe count number of vowels?

Comment: If the input could be either from the console or a file, you'll need separate methods for reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

From a discussion on the [NLTK google group](https://groups.google.com/group/nltk-users/browse_thread/thread/9823a1feeed5f3f2/81e70cb6704dc01e?pli=1):

```
import curses 
from curses.ascii import isdigit 
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import cmudict

d = cmudict.dict() 

def nsyl(word): 
  return [len(list(y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1]))) for x in d[word.lower()]]
```

This should be able to give you a syllable count for each word. Hope this helps.